# rails 4 rake aborted! on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration

rake db:migrate runs fine in development, as does the app. Only with heroku am i experience trouble

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate

Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.5905
-- create_table(:users)
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::MigrationProxy#disable_ddl_transaction delegated to 
migration.disable_ddl_transaction, but migration is nil: 
#<struct ActiveRecord::MigrationProxy name="DeviseCreateAdmins", 
version=20130802210826, filename="/app/db/migrate/20130802210826_devise_create_admins.rb", 
scope=""
```

Migration file:

```
class DeviseCreateAdmins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  create_table :users do |t|
    t.database_authenticatable
    t.confirmable
    t.recoverable
    t.rememberable
    t.trackable
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Does anyone have any ideas about why the migrations are failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a method name,

```
class DeviseCreateAdmins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.database_authenticatable
      t.confirmable
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

notice the `def change` at the beginning.

Comment: ahhh. so simple, and it was right in front of me! thanks john!